# Why Is this function producing NaN in the DOM?(React)

Tags: reactjs

So I'm working on this portion of an app where I want the number displayed on the page to increase or decrease depending on the hour of the day. At this point I'm using `componentDidMount()` to use a `setInterval()` method that takes in a function ( `hourCheck` ) and an interval.

However, `hourCheck` is having issues, specifically it's returning NaN in the DOM instead of an actual number. Seems like the state isn't being changed correctly but I'm exactly sure in what way.

Here's the app.js file I'm working with. I set the interval to 8000ms for the sake of time. This is ultimately a counter app.

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import { Wrapper } from "./components/Wrapper";
import Title from "./components/Title";
import Count from "./components/Count";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    CountNum: 0,
    
  };

  

 setCountNum = (val) => {
   this.setState({CountNum: val})
 }

 hourCheck = (val) => {

  



  let hourCount = new Date().getHours()

  
  

  if (hourCount >= 9 && hourCount <= 17) {
    this.setState({ CountNum: val + 1 });
  } else if (hourCount <= 8) {
    this.setState({ CountNum: val - 1});
  } else if (hourCount >= 18) {
    this.setState({ CountNum: val - 1});
  }

  console.log(hourCount)
};

loginSomething = (val) => {
  console.log(this.state.HourNum)
};





  render()
   {
    return (
      <Wrapper setCountNum={this.setCountNum} CountNum={this.state.CountNum}>
        <Title>Click Counter</Title>
        <Title>Count:</Title>
        <Count>{this.state.CountNum}</Count>
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    setInterval(this.hourCheck, 8000);
    
     };
  
}



export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

hourCheck function has val parameter and you are not passing that argument in setInterval in componentDidMount. Bind "this" obj to the hourCheck function in setInterval.

Comment: Can you point me to an article to learn more on this? I'm not familiar.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: This is what I changed setInterval() to, it's not working but is it close? ////. setInterval(this.hourCheck.bind(this.state.CountNum), 8000)

Comment: could you specify what "this" obj is? I thought it'd be this.stat.CountNum but no luck. Unless there's more code to do.

Comment: it should be setInterval(this.hourCheck.bind(this,this.state.CountNum), 8000)